# HTML Layout on Mirror View?

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

How do the webpage on mirror view. My webpage must be compatible with
English and arabic languages. While user selecting Arabic language the
web page convert into mirror view of normal layout of English. Any
layout kit is there for suitable with normal and mirror view in 960.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `dir="rtl"` to your HTML element to make the text right to left, e.g.

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

It's also a good idea to mention it's Arabic there as well:

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
```

You can also use the `dir` attribute on elements: e.g.

```
<div dir="rtl">This is right to left</div>
```

That means if your site breaks if the whole page is rtl, you can just target little bits.

Comment: Amazing Mr .Rich. The layout are floated to right. Thats is only i want. Thanks Rich.